# Prove the existence of $F \in \Lambda$ such that $Fx = xF$ for arbitrary variable $x \in \Lambda$

Tags: lambda-calculus

I recently met the problem as indicated in the title: find an $F \in \Lambda$ such that $Fx = xF$ for arbitrary variable $x \in \Lambda$. I am not only seeking a solution, but also a systematic way to think about such problems. Could someone help?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the context?

Comment: Hint: $F = \lambda x. x F$, which is a fixpoint equation.

Comment: @gist076923 Actually, I got what Trebor told me. I will proceed to think about it.

Comment: What does $\Lambda$ mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Set of lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution after reviewing [materials from Harvard](https://groups.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs152/2022sp/index.html). From
\begin{equation}
F = \lambda x. xF,
\end{equation}
we may define
\begin{equation}
F^{\prime} = \lambda t. \lambda x. x\left(tt\right).
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
F = F^{\prime}F^{\prime}.
\end{equation}

Indeed, without reading the materials, I couldn't have solved this problem.